# Charging other Stripe Merchants

Tags: payment, stripe-payments

I'm developing a donation platform on which I'll be taking a fee and am looking into using Stripe, but I'm snagged on one point that I haven't found any documentation for thus far.

Stripe doesn't handle chained payments, but does mention in their FAQ that: "If you want to collect a fee on the transactions, you can charge these merchants with your API key using Stripe."

Anyone know of some documentation or examples I could reference for this?  Or could anyone point me in the right direction with their existing docs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Stripe doesn't handle chained payments, but does mention in their FAQ that: "If you want to collect a fee on the transactions, you can charge these merchants with your API key using Stripe."

This just means your platform's users can pay you via credit card, and you can charge these cards with your Stripe API key. If you email support@stripe.com with more details on your setup, we can help you decide how to best structure your platform payments. Also feel free to jump into our chatroom at https://stripe.com/campfire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  For clarification, looks like the process would be to have a merchant setup a Stripe account, then have them hand me their prod API key and also give me their CC info so that I can handle (1) direct donations from users to the merchants and (2) charge a fee to them accordingly for transactions respectively.

Comment: btw, just jumped over to the campfire chat to ask more of the structural questions.

Comment: super helpful in the chat, thanks again.  They recommended I check out the Shopify - Stripe integration as it handles the same workflow I'm investigating.